# DefaultSignatures and associated type families

Tags: haskell, type-families

Is there a way to use `DefaultSignatures` extension with associated type families.

Here is an example why I need it.

```
class Foo p where
  type Back p :: *
  type Forward p :: *
  customFunc :: p -> IO ()

newtype Bar a = Bar (Forward a)

data Bat = Bat

type family ForwardBar a :: *

type instance ForwardBar Bat = Int

instance Foo (Bar Bat) where
  type Back (Bar Bat) = Bat
  type Forward (Bar Bat) = ForwardBar Bat
  customFunc _ = print "I am different customFunc and this is Bat Bat"
```

Now I want whenever `p ~ Bar x` then `type Back (Bar x) = x` and `type ForwardBar (Bar x) = Forward x`. I want to auto derive this whenever I am defining instance for some `Bar x`. However, definition of customFunc is different. Is this possible?

Also is it possible to add default signatures to functions of a class in another file (or package). I am using some class which I want to add default signatures but I dont want to modify the class definition itself.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, there's currently no possibility to use `DefaultSignatures` with type families.

I can see two options to do what you want. Both have certain disadvantages, but perhaps they're sufficient for your purposes.

#### Option 1: Use normal associated type default definitions

```
class Foo p where
  type Back p :: *
  type Back p = UnBar p
  type Forward p :: *
  type Forward p = ForwardBar (UnBar p)
  customFunc :: p -> IO ()
```

Requires a helper type family `UnBar`:

```
type family UnBar a :: *
type instance UnBar (Bar a) = a
```

The instance can then be just:

```
instance Foo (Bar Bat) where
  customFunc _ = print "I am different customFunc and this is Bat Bat"
```

#### Option 2: Use type families instead

```
class Foo p where
  customFunc :: p -> IO ()

type family Back p :: *
type family Forward p :: *
```

Now we can give a general instance for the type families for all `Bar` types:

```
type instance Back (Bar a) = a
type instance Forward (Bar a) = ForwardBar a
```

And more specific instances for the class, for concrete `Bar` types:

```
instance Foo (Bar Bat) where
  customFunc _ = print "I am different customFunc and this is Bat Bat"
```

Comment: Can you comment on the disadvantages of both ways.

Comment: @Satvik With Option 1, you can only give one default. Although that's not too bad, because the default can be an arbitrary type family again, having many special cases. But it requires `UndecidableInstances` in most cases. With Option 2, it's more than just a default. You couldn't give a more specific instance for `Back (Bar Bat)` even if you wanted to, as "overlapping" type family instances aren't possible.